# jQuery: Select last match before specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a way in jQuery to, given an element and a selector, select the last match of that selector before that element from an in-order traversal of the DOM tree?

For example, given the DOM tree:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="a" id="div0" />
    <div>
      <div class="a" id="div1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="b" id="div2"/>
    <div id="element"/>
    <div class="a" id="div3"/>
    <div class="b" id="div4"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using the selector `.a` and element `#element`, you'd get `#div1`, and using the selector `.b` and the element `#element`, you'd get `#div2`.

The use case is writing a GreaseMonkey script to work across different versions of Firefox with some slightly mangled HTML.  I've got an element I can find consistently in all versions, but another element I want to find is either a previous sibling of an ancestor of the element or a descendent of a previous sibling of an ancestor of the element (depending on the version).

All I can really rely on is that it is the last match of the selector that occurs before the element I have when doing an in-order traversal of the DOM tree.

Comment: I find real HTML is easier to read the pseudo code like this.

Comment: I've previously written a `realPrev` plugin. See: [jQuery .prev() of a type regardless of it's parent etc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7771241/938089?jquery-prev-of-a-type-regardless-of-its-parent-etc). In your case, you can use: `$('#element').realPrev('.a,#element');`

Comment: -1 because of the poorly formated NOT html which makes it very hard to determine the closures/wraps of the divs in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, using your first example:

```
var $collection = $(".a, #element");

var eleIndex = $collection.index($("#element"));

var prevEl = $collection.eq(eleIndex - 1);

alert(prevEl.attr("id"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WdsGa/

Comment: Come to think of it, mine is quite similar to your answer as well.

Comment: and for whatever reason, `$collection.index` wasn't working under old Firefox (my guess is equality on XPCNativeWrappers), so I had to do that bit manually.  But still, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sortof. This will work for sibling elements just fine:

```
$("div.a:first").nextUntil("#element").last();
```

however, your nested div.a will not work with that snippet, I'm not sure of an efficient way to solve that. It selects the first element matched by `div.a`, then all siblings after it until it finds an element that matches `#element`, and then gets the last of those selected elements. But, again, it only works with siblings.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
var last = $(".a, #element").eq($(".a, #element").length-1);
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding this, all it does is reproduce jquery's `last` in a less efficient way.  http://api.jquery.com/last/