# jQuery - if else click event

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery and just playing around right now. I'm trying to create a click event which has to the the attribute 'disabled' for a `<select></select>` to true/false whenever it's clicked.

So it's starting on disabled[true] and when clicking on a link it's going to disabled[false] - cool. But now I wan't to make it possible to set it back to disabled[true] with the same link.

My code is as following:

```
$('.enableSelects').click(function(){
    if($('select').is(':hidden')){
        $('select').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('select').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: The `:hidden` selector literally means it is hidden and not disabled.  Try `if($('select').attr('disabled')==false)` instead.

Comment: short version: http://jsfiddle.net/k3sb8/

Comment: @Yoshi Hey Yoshi. Could you throw an answer and describe the code a bit please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regarding the short version:

```
$('.enableSelects').click(function(){
    $('select').prop('disabled', !$('select').prop('disabled'));
});​
```

starting with:

```
$('select').prop('disabled', !$('select').prop('disabled'));
//          |                ||__________________________|
//          |                |  |
//          |                |  |_1) this will be evaluated first, resulting
//          |                |       in either 'true' or 'false'
//          |                |
//          |                |____2) the boolean value from above will then
//          |                        be inverted, and this new value will be
//          |                        used as the new value for disabled,
//          |                        which is then assigned
//          |
//          |_____________________3) using the 'prop' method
```

a slightly better version:

```
$('.enableSelects').click(function(){

    //                            |-- 1) this function gets called by jQuery
    //                            |      automatically. The index and the current
    //                            |      value will be passed to it.
    //                            |      The return value will be assigned to the
    //                            |      property.
    //                            |
    $('select').prop('disabled', function (idx, current) {

       // we're returning the inverted current value
       return !current;

    });
});​
```

it's basically the same as above, but we're reducing the number of selectors which have to be evaluated.

http://jsfiddle.net/k3sb8/1/

Comment: Hm, I don't quite get it. But I'll get it in time when I'll played a bit with it my self :-)

Comment: Btw, I have to click the link 2 times before it'll react. How come?

Comment: @Kolind mhm, for me it works the first click, what browser are you using?

Comment: And one more thing - How do I change the value of my input[button] regarding it's disabled or not?

Comment: Chrome - your jsfiddle works perfect, but not when I've inserted to my own code. I think it's because my select's is set disabled as default?

Comment: @Kolind I wouldn't think so. As add `disabled` to the select in the fiddle. It's also working. Maybe you can add some more of your code the the question.

Comment: I'm using the updated method you provided, and now it's working. No double clicking and so on. How do I change the value of my button regarding it's disabled or not? :)

Comment: Btw, you explanation of the updated version was a lot easier for me to understand, nice. :-)

Comment: Works just perfect! Damn, It's awesome :o) You'll get my check-mark :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `:disabled` instead of `:hidden`, and prefer [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) over [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Also, your current method works fine when there's only one `<select>` in your document. Change the selector when you've got multiple `<select>` elements.

Comment: I'll look at prop(). It's enabling both selects right now, isn't that good enough? What selector should I use for multiple select's?

Comment: @Kolind If you want to select all `<select>`s, then your current code is fine. I just noted that, because it's a common mistake for novice jQuery users to use `$('selector')` with the intend of selecting *one* element, and then getting surprised that all elements are selected. For multiple `<select>`, you might want another solution though: **See http://pastebin.com/NwsWvu7R**. It switches the visibility for **all** individual `<select>` elements.

Comment: My intention was to enable all select on page. But then after a quick thought I don't wanna enable all select's on the page. I wanna pick the selects in the next div#editMain.. Is that possible?

Comment: @Kolind That's possible. To answer that question, it's easier when you provide your DOM structure. Otherwise, adjust the [`realPrev`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7771241/938089?jquery-prev-of-a-type-regardless-of-its-parent-etc) jQuery plugin so that it becomes "realNext" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up on [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/561731)

Try using `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Try using @Yoshi's fiddle from the comments: http://jsfiddle.net/k3sb8/